# upload file to another domain Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have "www.mine.com/one" and "www.mine.com/two".
I want to upload a file from form in "www.mine.com/two" to folder "images" in "www.mine.com/one". I dont know how to realize it. Do I need to change the folder permission to 777 ?
I've tried upload existing file (img_1.jpg)  with ftp protocol like this.

```
$remote_file = 'http://mine.com/one/images/';
$ftp_host = 'localhost'; 
$ftp_user_name = 'mine'; 
$ftp_user_pass = 'mine123'; 
$local_file = 'http://mine.com/two/uploads/img_1.jpg';                               
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

if(ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass )){
   if ( ftp_put($remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
      redirect('SUCCESS');
  }
  else {
     redirect('FAIL');
  }
}
```

The result always redirect to 'FAIL'. Can u help me?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote here `local_file = 'http://mine.com/two/uploads/img_1.jpg;`

Comment: You should not have to change the permission to 777 as long as the ftp user have the permission to write in the folder. Have you tried connecting qith a 'regular' ftp client(ei: filezilla)

Comment: yes i've edited it. I accidentally deleted it :). But it still 'FAIL' @LouisLoudogTrottier .

Comment: yes, then? @LouisLoudogTrottier

Comment: Do you have any errors in your log?

Answer (score 0):

Humm, seems like you are connecting to your "localhost" and then try to upload the file to http://mine.com/one/images/, These 2 lines can't works together:

```
$remote_file = 'http://mine.com/one/images/';
$ftp_host = 'localhost';
```

It needs to be more something like where the remote file is relative to your ftp root folder and is missing the file name

```
$remote_file = '/one/images/img_1.jpg';
```

Also, you are missing the 1st argument of `ftp_put` that needs to be ressources:

```
  if ( ftp_put($remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
```

should be

```
 if ( ftp_put($connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
```

Hope this helps,
See many example and documentation here:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php

in your case see these:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php and 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php

Comment: well thankyou so much for your answer :D
It works now. 

I use ftp->upload($source, ".".$destination).
I declare "uploads/img_1.jpg " as $source and "/one/images/img_1.jpg" as $destination.

The flow is i upload my file into my local folder (uploads/img_1.jpg) first, then i use ftp->upload to upload file from my local folder into /one/images/img_1.jpg

Comment: Sometimes a little explaination can help more than just re-coding stuff for others. Glad you made it work. Keep it up.